# Magento 2: How to upgrade specific module?

Tags: magento2

Upgrading all module using `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` require time to complete. I have a local module which I upgraded always so I want to execute update only this module. How do we achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean composer update or setup:upgrade or something else?

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: You can't use `setup:upgrade` for specific modules. The optional `--keep-generated` option should be used only in limited circumstances by experienced system integrators. `--keep-generated` should never be used in a development environment. if its going really slow, You should fix Your local env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably figured this out already. I thought of placing this answer incase someone else runs into the same question.

1. Make sure you backup the DB and Files
2. Enable the site maintenance mode

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable

3. Update Module

> composer update vendor/module-name

depending the system user you might need to reassign file/directory permissions.

4. upgrade magento DB and file

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated

5. Recreate DI

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

6. Deploy static content

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

7. Clear Cache

> php bin/magento cache:clean

8. Disable the site maintenance mode

> php bin/magento maintenance:disable